# Adding dictionaries to GoldenDict

Tags: dictionary

I have GoldenDict installed in my Ubuntu 10.10. I am downloading [A Spanish-English Dictionary](http://www.babylon.com/free-dictionaries/education/libraries/A-Spanish-English-Dictionary-%28Granada-University,-Spain%29,-10.5/57962.html) in order to add it into the dictionary database of GoldenDict.

Once I add a path to search for the dictionary files and click on **Rescan Now** button in order to tell GoldenDict to index the new dictionary GoldenDict starts to index the dictionary and this process doesn't finish never. GoldenDict hangs on so that I need to kill it from the process. The dictionary I am trying to add is a file of 23.5Mb. I could add other dictionaries of 8-10Mb but not this one.

Any idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem of GoldenDict with looping while attempting to import the dictionary.

I was running GoldenDict in Guest Machine of VirtualBox and I only dedicated 1Gb of memory to the Guest Machine. I had noticed that when you give GoldenDict big dictionaries to index it consumes a lot of memory. So in my case it run out the memory (1Gb) and therefore were looping and hanging on.

I added another 1Gb of memory (so totaly I dedicated 2Gb memory) to the Guest Machine and tried to perform to import the dictionary again. This time GoldenDict could do its job, because it had sufficient memory to perform its tasks.

Answer (score 5):

Goldendict is looping while attempting to import the dictionary, it is a bug, you should file a bug report:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own path to the collection of your dictionaries in the Goldendict interface.

1. `sudo goldendict` (you may want to use sudo if goldendict builds index files in the folders where the su privileges are required)
2. Edit->Dictionaries->Sources/Files. Press "Add" and navigate to the folder with the collection of your dictionaries. (In my case it was a subdirectory in Home, but with `sudo goldendict` any directory should work)
3. Select the directory with all dictionaries (not the individual files) and press Open.
   I hope this helps.